# User input sanitization program, which takes a specific amount of arguments and passes the execution to a bash script

Tags: arrays, c, string, strcpy, strlen

I am trying to write a little program, which is resistant against buffer overflow and similar vulnerabilities.

Since we cannot trust the user input, I thought it would be a good idea to concatenate all the strings that are inputted into one string and then pass it to a static path, which is a bash script in the same folder and then add all the parameters/flags/arguments (e.g. ./script.sh test1 test2 test3 test4).

My logic on paper is the following:

1. Check whether the number of argc is 5 exactly (so program name + the 4 arguments), if not - exit immediately
2. The specific char array for 5 strings (so array elements) with a max length of 4096 bytes length is initialized.
3. Since `argv[0]` is equal to the program name, we need to skip it. Hence the loop starts at 1 (first argument) and ends at argc-1. So good so far
4. We append the argv[1] string the ending `.key` in-memory.
5. We `memcpy` all the strings to make it safe to use
6. For each iteration we don't forget to add the null terminator at the end of the string.
7. After we have all the arguments safe to use we concat it in the function parse_output and call the bash script called script.sh and add all the required arguments
8. We return the output from the `script.sh 4argshere` to the user

I tried freeing the memory like in the comments but it seems to not work or I have errors somewhere else.

My segfaulting Proof of Concept:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1000

char *concatenate(size_t size, char *array[size], const char *joint);

char *concatenate(size_t size, char *array[size], const char *joint){
    size_t jlen, lens[size];
    size_t i, total_size = (size-1) * (jlen=strlen(joint)) + 1;
    char *result, *p;


    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        total_size += (lens[i]=strlen(array[i]));
    }
    p = result = malloc(total_size);
    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        memcpy(p, array[i], lens[i]);
        p += lens[i];
        if(i<size-1){
            memcpy(p, joint, jlen);
            p += jlen;
        }
    }
    *p = '\0';
    return result;
}


int parse_output(char *safeargv[]) {
    char safeargs = *concatenate(5, safeargv, " ");

    char cmd[BUFSIZE];
    snprintf(cmd, BUFSIZE, "./script.sh %s", safeargs);

    char buf[BUFSIZE] = {0};
    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp = popen(cmd, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening pipe!\n");
        //free(safeargs);
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("OUTPUT: %s", buf);
    }

    if (pclose(fp)) {
        printf("Command not found or exited with error status\n");
       //free(safeargs);
        return -1;
    }
    //free(safeargs);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc != 5) {
        exit(1);
    }

    char *safeargv[5][4096];

    for (int i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++) {
        if (i == 1)
            strcat(argv[1], ".key");
        for (int x = 0; x < strlen(argv[i]); x++) {
            char *unsafe_string = argv[i];
            size_t max_len = 4096;
            size_t len = strnlen(unsafe_string, max_len) + 1;
            char *x = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
            if (x != NULL) {
                strncpy(x, unsafe_string, len);
                x[len-1] = '\0'; // Ensure null-termination
                strcpy(safeargv[i], x);
                free(x);
            }
        }
    }
    parse_output(safeargv);
    return 0;
}
```

The warnings I get while compiling:

```
chal.c: In function 'main':
chal.c:78:32: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   78 |                 strcpy(safeargv[i], x);
      |                        ~~~~~~~~^~~
      |                                |
      |                                char **
In file included from chal.c:2:
/usr/include/string.h:141:39: note: expected 'char * restrict' but argument is of type 'char **'
  141 | extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
      |                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
chal.c:83:18: warning: passing argument 1 of 'parse_output' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   83 |     parse_output(safeargv);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~
      |                  |
      |                  char * (*)[4096]
chal.c:32:24: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char * (*)[4096]'
   32 | int parse_output(char *safeargv[]) {
      |                  ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems only my argc check works, because if I call ./programname abc abc abc abc it segfaults. Also what's the proper way to detect an error, if for case there's a typo in the argument for the script?

What mistake(s) did I make?

My last `ltrace` lines:

```
strlen(" ")                                                                                                                                                                                         = 1
strlen(nil <no return ...>
```

It looks as if it would try to detect the length of a null character or similar.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I can't speak for windows, but for linux (i.e. posix), the `argv` from an `exec*` call is passed into the _kernel_. The kernel checks these when creating `argv` (via `copy_from_user` for parent and `copy_to_user` for child) in the target program address space. So, _no_ need to copy out `argv` from a program `main` as it is _already_ "safe". As long as you stay within the bounds of the `argv` array, you're fine. In other words, the `argv` sent via `exec*` is _not_ blindly used as is. The kernel probes each element and copies it to a new area (checking along the way).

Comment: @CraigEstey I am using Linux. So you're saying all the `memcpy` and etc. is only security theater in this case? A simple `while(*argv != NULL)` is enough then?

Comment: Yes, the kernel "sanitizes" all elements of the `argv` that is passed to `main` (and better as the strings can be > 4096 (IIRC)?). There is a similar `char*` array for the environment variables. When doing `exec*`, the parent can put the `argv` anywhere in its memory. The kernel when copying into the target, starts at the highest [virtual] address, growing the area downward. Ditto for `environ`. The initial stack pointer is set just below those. Try printing (via `%p`) the addresses of `argv` in both caller/callee (as well as stack pointer). sp < argv < environ for callee (e.g.)

Comment: For a deep dive, get the linux kernel source. Many ways to get the kernel source, but Linus' git repo can be gotten via: `git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git` Look in the file `fs/exec.c`. Look at the `copy_strings` function. For the limits, look in `include/uapi/linux/binfmts.h` (for `MAX_ARG_STRLEN`). It is 32 pages (_not_ 1). And, up to 0xFFFFFFFF separate `argv` entries. The max number of pages devoted to args is 32

Comment: @CraigEstey I think you're right: `args from 0 to 4:
0xffffff92
”0xffffffde
”0xffffffd8
0x35
0xfffffffc`